# How to use a configuration file for controlling variables

Tags: php, ini

I'm coding a theme and i want to create a configuration file (maybe ini) to control variables in the theme
For example,
I want to have a file with simple content like this

```
navigation: 1;
site_name: MYSITE;
```

^ dunno if the syntax is right...just an example

And then i want to use that file to show the content stored in those variables.

**for example :**

shows the value entered in the file

i also want to show/hide specific content based on the Boolean value entered in the value (navigation: 1 or 0)
something like

I hope i'm understandable. I'm a noob in PHP :'>

Comment: That is simple enough. thank =)
then what i the difference between INI files and defining variables in PHP file? just that ini file has much simpler formation? =/

Comment: Using a php file, you have to make sure you filter it, so when you include the file, it doesn't overwrite any variables in the system. With a ini/json file, not only does it have functions to easily parse the files, but makes them interchangeable between programs if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps take a look at [`parse_ini_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

Answer (score 2):

I moved away from .ini files when I discovered json. Makes everything so easy.

```
$filePath = "/var/www/config.json";

// Puts the config into an array
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath));

// Saves array back to config file
file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode($config));
```